# In iOS, How do other applications write PPT files into the inbox path of their own sandbox?

Tags: ios, sandbox

I have a requirement now, and I want to display a PPT file in my app using WebView. However, this PPT file is downloaded from other applications,When I click "open from other applications" button in other app,select own app and click Import the PPT file.Then jump to my app interface. After that, I saw this PPT file in my app sandbox/Inbox path. I want to know how this file is passed into my application sandbox? Is that perform any method? I need to intercept this process and do something.Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Your App Delegate is called with the URL of the sanbox/Inbox file.

See:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623112-application